# How did Eastern Orthodoxy view mental illness before modern times?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, demons, ecclesiology, demon-possession, mental-illness

In Eastern-Orthodoxy, in the medieval times like the Byzantine Empire, Russian Empire. etc.
How did the Church and the priest saw people who today we know suffer from mental illness like bipolar, schizophrenia, paranoia, etc.?
What this seen as a spiritual problem? Possibly demonic activity or demonic possession? How was it treated?

Comment: For illness, there is the sacrament of holy unction; for the possessed, there are the prayers of John Chrysostom and Basil the Great.

Comment: Lucian. Sure, but my question was if in the past, people who where sick of metal illness s, not demon possessed. Where systematically "diagnosed" as possessed?

Comment: Only some of the mentally afflicted are violent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did any Church Fathers write anything about mental illnesses?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79541/did-any-church-fathers-write-anything-about-mental-illnesses)